# Why is `a = a` `nil` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, local-variables

I watched this [video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). Why is `a = a` evaluated to `nil` if `a` is not defined?

```
a = a # => nil
b = c = q = c # => nil
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Ruby interpreter initializes a local variable with `nil` when it sees an assignment to it. It initializes the local variable before it executes the assignment expression or even when the assignment is not reachable (as in the example below). This means your code initializes `a` with `nil` and then the expression `a = nil` will evaluate to the right hand value.

```
a = 1 if false
a.nil? # => true
```

The first assignment expression is not executed, but `a` is initialized with `nil`.

You can find this behaviour documented in the Ruby [assignment documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods).