# Why does a = a evaluate to nil?

Tags: ruby, behavior, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why a = a is nil in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-a-a-is-nil-in-ruby)

In the humorous [lightning talk - Wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) delivered by Gary Bernhardt, the following code evaluates to nil:

```
a = a
#=> nil
```

But anything other than self assignment results in a NameError

```
b = c
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `c' for main:Object
```

Can somebody please explain why `a = a` evaluates to `nil`?

Answer (score 2):

Because assignment to `a` creates `a` for that scope. assignment to `b` doesn't create `c`.