# Why can I assign an undefined variable to itself in Ruby and get nil?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, internals, ruby-1.9.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why a = a is nil in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-a-a-is-nil-in-ruby)

There's a, shall we say, *"odd phenomenon"* in Ruby with using undefined variables. It's like this:

```
# irb session follows
#
foo        # undefined local variable or method 'foo'
bar        # same for 'bar'
foo = bar  # still same for 'bar'
foo = foo  # nil - HUH?
foo        # is now set to nil!?
```

**Why can I assign an undefined variable to itself in Ruby and get `nil`**?

Note that I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 here. I'm not sure what other versions this may be true in.

(Thanks to Gary Bernhardt for demonstrating this in his [hilarious talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).)

Comment: Presumably, `foo = foo` is evaluated in two steps. The first one "declares" the variable with a default value, and the second one assigns it to itself.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that bar is undefined is actually not the most interesting part, since the assignment does not even need to be attempted, for example

```
if false
  foo = 1
end
```

Sets foo to nil. As i understand it, local variable scope is determined statically in that it is determined without actually running the code, merely by analysing it. Ruby thinks the assignment could happen so it creates the local variable and sets it to nil. See http://ruby.runpaint.org/variables#local

Comment: Even better, the variable to be assigned in the if statement doesn't have to be defined: `foo = wat if false`

Comment: link from the post is dead

Answer (score 2):

Nil is magic in Ruby, because of the idea that everything is an object. There is actually a singleton nil object that gets assigned. When you did

```
foo = bar
```

the "foo" variable sprang into existence and took as value the magic nil object. Before you did the assignment, Ruby didn't have a way of "knowing" what foo is (is it a variable? a method call?), but once you do the assignment, it starts treating it as a variable.

Comment: Well, `foo = foo` also works without any prior statements.

Comment: It sure does, and for the same reason. The nil is not the thing - that's just a placeholder for an undefined value. The thing is the assignment, once Ruby sees the assignment, it "decides" to treat the token to the left of the "=" as a variable.

Comment: @theglauber, That doesn't quite explain `foo = foo`. In the case of `foo = bar` if both foo and bar are undefined an exception is still raised. The odd case of `foo = foo` working is due to the fact that the ruby interpreter performs initialization prior to expression evaluation. Essentially on the left hand foo is inited to nil; then by the time the interpreter reaches the expression evaluation to do the assignment the foo on the right hand side has already been initialized.