# Why x = x does not raise an error even if x is undefined

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is `a = a` `nil` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-is-a-a-nil-in-ruby)

I'm sure there is a reason for this behavior i'm just curious what it is.

```
y = x # NameError: undefined local variable or method 'x'
x = x # => nil
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-is-a-a-nil-in-ruby

Comment: Thank you, sorry about the duplicate I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the way variables are initialized in Ruby, which is rather unique to this language. Basically, Ruby initializes (creates) a variable if it could possibly get assigned a value. Consider this example:

```
if false
  x = "hello"
end
```

`x` will definitely not get assigned the `"hello"` string here. However, it will still get initialized with `nil` as from the static program analysis, it could have been assigned.

Your example is similar. Because you assign something to `x`, it will get initialized with `nil` *before* the statement is executed. Thus, during execution, `x` is in fact `nil`.