# defined? weirdness

Tags: ruby

There was a weird thing I encountered in Ruby this morning, concerning the ternary operator. Here how it goes:

```
x = nil ? x : true
```

As known to all, `x` is set to **true**, no surprise there. Now, subsequentlyl running:

```
defined?(y) 
=> nil
```

This answer would imply `y` has not been defined yet. However:

```
defined?(y) ? y : true
```

Returns **true**. No surprise again. The surprise comes here:

```
y = defined?(y) ? y : true
```

and what happens? `y` is set to `nil`!

But wait, there is more. Now since `y` is assigned, let's work with `z`:

```
defined?(z) 
#=> nil
```

Implying `z` is not defined yet.

```
z = defined?(z) ? false : true
```

And the suprise: `z` is set to **false**. I have no idea how that happens. Doing the same in an `if` block gives the same result.

```
z1 = if defined?(z1) then z1 else true end
```

Again `z1` is set to `nil`.

```
z2 = if defined?(z2) then false else true end
```

This, too, gives me a surprise, as `z2` is set to `false`. Now I was assuming the above expression to behave something like:

```
z3 = if nil then false else true end
```

where `z3` gets assigned to `true`, considering the fact that `defined?` returned `nil` in all the above cases. This makes me believe that there is something special at work around `defined?` call, but I could find no information on it in Ruby documentation.

Btw. I tested the above on ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-is-a-a-nil-in-ruby

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not sure why it fall in same category though

Comment: @Viren: Because it's not about `defined?`, it's about how assignemnt works in ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Just check that last edit If you can the last thing I will be happy to let this question closed i.e  `y = (defined?(y) ? y : true )`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev point accepted though but my point is this  `^^` then should not work the way I mention

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Ok pls don't delete it, I just rewrote it into English :-)

Comment: @Viren: no, it's functioning as it should. Ruby initializes left-side to `nil` before evaluating right-side. So it's essentially this: `y = nil; y = (defined?(y) ? y : true )`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Point very well taken thanks one can close the question if they feel like closing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think this explains it:

```
ccc = (ccc == nil)
=> true
```

Apparently, whenever you assign something to a variable, ruby first initializes it to nil.

Comment: Point accepted does that defined why the `if` is functioning differently in above case

Comment: One more point is `y = (defined?(y) ? y : true) ` yield the same result as describe by me above i.e y getting set to `nil`

Comment: yup perhaps that explain the above