# Is `x = x` a documented or acceptable way to initialize a local variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have noticed that in Ruby the code `x = x` initializes a local variable `x` with `nil` if `x` is not defined. This can be used, for example, in an ERB template to check if a local variable is defined and has a "true-ish" value:

```erb
<% if header = header %>
  <h1><%= header %></h1>
<% end %>
```

So, is this a feature or a bug?  Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: You are just a beginner. Don't expect to have found a bug that no one else has listed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is \`a = a\` \`nil\` in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-is-a-a-nil-in-ruby)

Comment: Well, i am more interested not i why it is implemented so, but in whether this is the expected and documented behavior.

Comment: While this works, it is a really bad way to do it. Most of the time, writing code is a long-term process. We write it, then we maintain it over a long term. Writing clearly and concisely makes it easier to maintain, for you or for those who inherit the code from you. Assignments in conditionals are the source of bugs because it's difficult to tell if that was intentional or accidental.

Comment: @theTinMan, the assignment in a conditional is not the point here, i could have initialized the header before with `header = header`. Would it be the good way?

Comment: No, it is not. It obscures your intention, and, why do that? Just because something works, if it's done differently than the normal way, you need to stop and think about the long-term implications. If there is a normal-practice, use it. `header ||= nil` isn't particular good either, but it's better than `header = header` because it's a normal idiom. In general I think the real problem occurs before that point, where header needs to be initialized ahead of time, or, just use `header.nil?`.

Answer (score 4):

This may work, but I think it disguises your intent.

If you want to check if something is defined then you should say that

```
if defined?(header) && header
```

however in partials I do normally default all values at the start of my template

eg (with haml)

```
- # input header is optional
- header ||= nil

- if header
  %h1 This is the header

%p this is the rest of the partial
```

Comment: I didn't know that `header ||= nil` also works.  I do not know which one is more natural then: initialize with `x ||= nil` or with `x = x`.

Answer (score -4):

This is neither a feature or a bug. You can simply test for the truthiness of the local variable by calling it, as if it is not initialized it will return nil by default.

```
<% if header %>
  <h1><%= header %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this true? I get `NameError` in this case.

Comment: You can only do this with instance variables, not local