# Difference between inline if conditional and block if conditional in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block, conditional-statements

Today I come across this weird behaviour of Ruby's inline if and block if

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > inline_if = 'value will not set but no error' if inline_if
 => nil 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > if block_if
2.0.0-p247 :003?>   block_if = 'forget about setting value, I will raise an error'
2.0.0-p247 :004?>   end
NameError: undefined local variable or method `block_if' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
```

What is the difference between inline if conditional and block if conditional?

Comment: Where have you defined `block_if` ?

Comment: `inline_if` and `block_if` both are undefined. But by using block if statement it's throwing error while inline is not throwing any error.

Comment: Here's another: `a = b.nil? => NameError: undefined local variable or method 'b' for main:Object`, but `a = a.nil? => true`. @YuHao explains why. Toward the end of one of his always-interesting [articles](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html), Peter Cooper put it this way: "That is, a variable assignment, even if not run, immediately summons that variable into being." Interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it has something to with ruby parser. Because when writing inline if

```
inline_if = 'value will not set but no error' if inline_if
```

Ruby parser actually parse from left to right. So in above line it first encounters setter method of variable `inline_if`. so it actually defines this variable with value `nil` and then it checks for the condition `if inline_if` which will be evaluated as `if nil`.

Now with the block if condition

```
if block_if
  block_if = 'forget about setting value, I will raise an error'
end
```

it first tries to access the `block_if` variable which is not yet defined. hence it will trow an error.

It's amazing thing that from programmer view both of above block should be evaluated equally. but they behave different

Answer (score 2):

See [Local Variables and Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs:
>
> ```
> a = 0 if false    # does not assign to a
> p local_variables # prints [:a]
> p a               # prints nil
> ```

In the first example, `inline_if` encountered first in assignment, so it is created(and has a value of `nil`). While in the second example, `block_if` is seen in the condition before it's seen in the assignment, which causes the error.

Comment: This is what I suspected, that parser must be defining the variable even if the statement isn't executed. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "Ruby interpreter initializes a local variable with nil when it sees an assignment to it."  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908103/1061413) to a related simpler question that highlights the crucial part of the behaviour you're seeing.

```
> a = a
# => nil (and assigns nil to a)
> b = c
# => NameError...
```

Also, watch this hilarious [video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) about JavaScript and Ruby oddities!