# Why let(:counter) { 0 } returns nil in example?

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Have two variables in Rspec, both of them are integers, but in example (in 'before' block) one of them is appropriate own value, another one is nil. Why?! Never heard about such a strange rspec behavior.

tried change 0 value to 1,
tried change the variable name,
tried change 'let' to 'let!',
but behavior didn't change.

The code is:

```
context 'when input contains incorrect symbols' do
      let(:counter) { 1 }
      let(:mocked_retry_count) { 5 }
      before do
        allow(described_class).to receive(:gets) {
          byebug
          counter += 1
          counter > mocked_retry_count ? 'Stop the loop' : ['$', (0..9).to_a.sample, '#', '%', '&'].sample
        }
        described_class.ask_kingdoms
      end
    end
```

In byebug's output I see that

```
   62:       let(:counter) { 1 }
   63:       let(:mocked_retry_count) { 5 }
   64:       before do
   65:         allow(described_class).to receive(:gets) {
   66:           byebug
=> 67:           counter += 1
   68:           counter > mocked_retry_count ? 'Stop the loop' : ['$', (0..9).to_a.sample, '#', '%', '&'].sample
   69:         }
   70:         described_class.ask_kingdoms
   71:       end
(byebug) counter
nil
(byebug) mocked_retry_count
5
```

What is the principal difference between 'counter' and 'mocked_retry_count' ? And how can I get my counter in example?

Comment: Its pretty unclear here what behavior this spec is actually trying to test but if you want to test that a method is called multiple times you would 
 use receive counts `expect(described_class).to receive(:gets).exactly(n).times`. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-8/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why `let(:counter) { 0 }` returns nil in example?

No, it doesn't. `counter` is not what you think it is. Try evaluating/printing `defined?(counter)` and `defined?(mocked_retry_count)`.

> What is the principal difference between 'counter' and 'mocked_retry_count' ?

You do not assign to `mocked_retry_count`. Remember, `let` creates methods. So when you attempt to assign to `counter`, you're creating a local variable `counter` which shadows your method `counter` (and has default value of `nil`).

This post explains in more detail: [Why is `a = a` `nil` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-is-a-a-nil-in-ruby)

Comment:   
`
(byebug) defined?(counter)
"local-variable"
(byebug) defined?(mocked_retry_count)
"method"
(byebug) counter
nil
(byebug) mocked_retry_count
5 
`

Comment: Yes, you're right, `counter` here is a `local variable` (but I still don't understand, why its `nil`) and `mocked_retry_count` is a `method`, and if I will rename `counter` to `counter_i`, its working as expected (because it became a `method`). I will read the link you shared, thank you so much, anyway!