# Why is `a => a` different to `a = a` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching, variable-assignment, local-variables

I understand why `a = a` in Ruby produces `nil` (see [Why is `a = a` `nil` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8908050)).

But using the rightwards assignment operator, `a => a` produces an error:

```
irb(main):001:0> a => a
(irb):1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

But when the right hand side is not a complex pattern, I thought `=>` should be exactly the same as `=`, just flipped.

So why does `a => a` not behave the same as `a = a`?

Comment: Probably because the parser is reading from left-to-right, and so it's now trying to **evaluate** `a` *before* it's trying to **assign** `a`. But I'd need to dig deep into ruby source code for absolute certainty on the explanation.

Comment: But it doesn't really matter, because this is a very weird thing to write in the code. I don't expect you will ever need to write code like this. (And nor should you ever need to write `a=a`! If you want to initialise `a` as `nil`, then why not put `a = nil` or `nil => a`?)

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't mind at all if `a = a` would raise a `NameError` too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [pattern matching](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html) docs we know that:

> `<expression> in <pattern>` is the same as `case <expression>; in <pattern>; true; else false; end`.

so:

```
a in a
```

is actually a shorthand for:

```
case a
in a
  true
else
  false
end
```

In the above `case` expression it's probably obvious that you would get a `NameError` on the very first line.

I assume `a => a` behaves similarly to `a in a` in regards to evaluation order.